# horizontal scroll bar on resizing browser and right white space on smaller screens

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

i'm getting horizontal scroll bar when resizing the browser to 796px or less i'v tried to delete the sections one by one to find which one gives that issue but it didn't resolve it then i tried to delete some code starting from section products-4 to the end of the code and it's solved then i started to delete the sections one by one from products-4 to the end but that didn't help i don't know what's the link between them to make that scroll appear and when try to test using google chrome device toolbar it gives white space on the right side with mobile screen resolution so i'v tried to delete any css code has any relationship with size for products-4 or for any other section below it but nothing happened so i hope you guys can help me to find where the problem is

```css
/* Products-4 */

#products-4{
    
    background-color: #000;
    margin-top:20px;
    color:darkred;
}


#products-4 img{
    border:1px solid white;
    border-radius:10px;
    padding:5px;
    
    
}

.col-centered{
float: none;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#products-4 h2 {
    text-align:center;
    
}

#products-4 p{
    text-align:center;
    
    
}




/* Team */

#team h2{
    
    text-align:center;
}
#team{
    text-align:center;
    
}
#team img{
    
    border:1px solid black;
    
}


/* Contact */


#contact{
    
    background-color: #000;
}

#contact .container{
    height:500px;
    
    
    
}

.tab-content{
    padding:50px;
    border:1px solid white;
    
    
}
.tab-content .tab-content-inside{
    
    padding:50px 0;
}

.tab-content .tab-content-inside a{
    color:white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.tab-content .tab-content-inside .btn{
    margin-top:30px;
   
    
}

.tab-content .tab-content-inside .btn-info{
    
    margin-left:50px;
}

.tab-content .tab-content-inside .btn-info a{
    
    padding-right:10px;
    padding-left:10px;
}

.nav-tabs li a{
    background-color: transparent !important;
    color:red;
    
    
}

.nav-tabs .active a{
    color:white !important;
    
}

.nav-tabs .active a:hover{
    color:cornflowerblue !important;
    
}

.nav-tabs li a:hover{
    background-color:white !important ;
    color:cornflowerblue;
    transition : all 1s;
    -webkit-transition : all 1s;
    -moz-transition : all 1s;
    -o-transition : all 1s;
    
    
    
}
```

```html
  <!-- Strart of products-4 --> 
       <section id="products-4">
          <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                  <h1 class="text-center">More Products</h1>
                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-3">
                          <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="img/polo-pro2.png">
                          <h2>Polo Shirts</h2>
                          <p>And Of Course Paragraph here</p>
                          
                      </div>
                      
                      <div class="col-md-3">
                          <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="img/polo-pro2.png">
                          <h2>Polo Shirts</h2>
                          <p>And Of Course Paragraph here</p>
                          
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-3">
                          <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="img/polo-pro2.png">
                          <h2>Polo Shirts</h2>
                          <p>And Of Course Paragraph here</p>
                          
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-3">
                          <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="img/polo-pro2.png">
                          <h2>Polo Shirts</h2>
                          <p>And Of Course Paragraph here</p>
                          
                      </div>
                      
                  </div>
                  
                  
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-3 col-centered">
                      <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="img/polo-pro2.png">
                          <h2>Polo Shirts</h2>
                          <p>And Of Course Paragraph here</p>
                          
                      
                  </div>
                  
                  
              </div>
          </div>
           
           
           
       </section>
       <!-- End of Products-4-->
       <!--Start of Team -->
       
       <section id="team">
           
           <div class="container">
               <div class="row">
                  <h1>Our Team</h1>
                  
                   
                   <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2">
                       <img src="img/face.png" class="img-circle" alt="">
                       <h2>The Manager</h2>
                       <p>Any pragraph here</p>
                       
                       
                   </div>
                   
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                       <img src="img/face.png" class="img-circle" alt="">
                       <h2>The Sales Man</h2>
                       <p>Any pragraph here</p>
                       
                       
                   </div>
                   
                   
               </div>
           </div>
           
           
       </section>
   
       <!-- End Of Team -->
       <!-- Start of contact -->
       <section id="contact">
           <div class="container">
               <div class="row">
                   <h1>Contact Us</h1>
                   <div class="row">
                       <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                           <li class="active">
                               <a data-toggle="tab" href="#e-mails">E-mails</a>
                               
                               
                           </li>
                           
                           <li>
                               <a data-toggle="tab" href="#phones">Phones</a>
                               
                           </li>
                           <li>
                               <a data-toggle="tab" href="#address">Address</a>
                               
                               
                           </li>
                           <li>
                               <a data-toggle="tab" href="#social">Social Networks</a>
                               
                           </li>
                           
                       </ul>
                       
                       <div class="tab-content">
                           <div id="e-mails" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                              <div class="tab-content-inside text-center">
                                  <h1>Feel Free To Text Us Any Time Using This E-Mails</h1>
                                  <div class="tab-content-content">
                                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                                          <span class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-2x">
                                              <a href="mailto:m.shawky@rt-wm.com">Manager</a>
                                              
                                          </span>
                                          
                                      </button>
                                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">
                                          <span class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-2x">
                                              <a href="mailto:m.shawky@rt-wm.com">Sales</a>
                                              
                                          </span>
                                          
                                      </button>
                                      
                                      
                                  </div>
                                  
                              </div>
                           </div>
                           <div id="phones" class="tab-pane fade">
                           All Phones Goes here 
                           
                           </div>
                           
                           <div id="address" class="tab-pane fade">
                               Address Comes here 
                               
                               
                           </div>
                           <div id="social" class="tab-pane fade">
                               Social Addresses goes here
                               
                               
                           </div>
                       </div>
                       
                       
                   </div>
                   
               </div>
           </div>
           
           
           
       </section>
   
       <!--end of contact-->
```

Comment: dirty hack: `html,body{ overflow-x: hidden;}`

Comment: well it has solved the problem but replicating my vertical scroll bar like i have 2 scroll bars now on the right side is that normal !?

Comment: try applying it only on body - exclude html

Comment: nice !! that's solved it thank you very much that was really help full